# How to attribute a users password to another in LInux

Tags: password

Here is the question: I want user A to have the same password as user B. How to do that?

Comment: Which OS? Any special authentication packages?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  Different users should have different passwords because that allows you to distinguish between them.  If more than one user knows the password of a certain user you might as well use a single account.

Comment: It was an exam question dude. I know that it is not an honest real life situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `/etc/shadow` file, copy the hash from user B over the hash of user A. That's it :)

Comment: Caveat: Every user with root access can now KNOW the fact the passwords are the same without needing to try. This may or may not be a problem; password salting was invented for exactly that reason :)

Comment: Caveat 2: whenever user A or B changes the password the paswords will not be in sync unless this procedure is repeated.  I doubt the OP is looking for something to set the passwords equal just once.  You might as well enter the same password twice.

Comment: @Bram: that would imply knowing user B's password ...